# LLVM support for GC while implementing a frontend for a managed memory language

Tags: compiler-construction, garbage-collection, llvm, llvm-ir, vm-implementation

I have a language compiled to a bytecode running on top of closed-source VM I don't have access to. I am examining options for creating a LLVM frontend for that language. One thing I am trying to understand is how Garbage Collector fits into that picture. I have no slightest desire to reimplement it. **Is there anything in LLVM that would take care of garbage collection in that specific case?** Since language I am dealing with bears resemblance to core Java I had a brief look at [java llvm frontend](https://llvm.org/svn/llvm-project/java/trunk) hosted under llvm project, but didn't find quick answers - I may have overlooked something easily as I am not very familiar with these things and there is not much documentation on that subproject. Repo seems quite stale as well with the last commit dating to 2007.

Comment: I don't know if this is of any help to you, but there are existing FOSS garbage collectors, like Boehm–Demers–Weiser. I think Mono (a free implementation of .NET) used it, so you may want to look at what they did and figure out if you can do something similar.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand after reading some LLVM docs, LLVM provides some hooks for garbage collectors but not more than that. In case anyone's interested I came across 2 open and proven implementations of GC:

- https://github.com/ivmai/bdwgc libgc used in new VM by Unity under the hood of IL2CPP
- https://github.com/mozilla/shumway mozilla's open implementation of flash player